# C# - Uncheck a radio button with a command

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have a button which, when clicked, should uncheck/deselect a radio button which was previously checked.

Just like we clear the text from a textbox when a button is clicked, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    textBox1.Clear();
  }
```

Is there a way to uncheck/deselect a radio button that was already checked?

Comment: WinForms? Wpf? Asp.net WebForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Clear();
    radioButton.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Marked as answer. I was going to mark it as answer instantly, but it said I had to wait 11 minutes.